# ios Facebook Login - FBSDKAccessToken is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

This is my code in the view-controller:

```
- (void) loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult: (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:   (NSError *)error{
     if ([[result token] tokenString]) {
          //send token to the server...
     }
}
```

I get Facebook token, but later on from some reason the FBSDKAccessToken turns to ***nil***

which means that the Facebook "log-out" button - turns to "Login"...

Comment: You mean you are able to print the `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]`?

Comment: at the beginning - and than it becomes nil

Comment: Are you sure you aren't logging the user out anywhere? Once the user has logged in using facebook successfully, there should always be a value for `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` till the user logs out.

Comment: @Rikh Thanks!!! that was indeed the problem! wanna write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the user logs into the application, unless you explicitly logout the user, a value for `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` will be present.

Just make sure you aren't accidentally logging the user out.